# Which relationship type to choose in Laravel Eloquent ORM on multiple relationships case

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent, table-relationships

I am new to Laravel and a bit confused about some definitions of ORM. 
I am currently working on a simple Trouble ticket management system, and here is my question :
(table: column, column,...) 
tickets : id, description, equipment_id 
equipments: id, name, vendor_id 
vendor: id, name

This is a very short resume of my tables and its relations, following Laravel's conventions. How can I build these models?

Basically I need to retrieve, for example, how many tickets were opened to a certain vendor (how many times I called the vendor for support).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What zwacky said is entirely (edit: maybe not entirely correct in the end) true for close relations, but in your situation there is nested relation:

```
Vendor -> Equipment -> Ticket
```

Then to retrieve tickets for particular vendor you would define relation on Vendor model like this:

```
class Vendor extends Eloquent {
  public function equipment()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Equipment');
  }
  public function tickets()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Ticket', 'Equipment');
  }


class Equipment extends Eloquent {
  public function tickets()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
  }
  public function vendor()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Vendor');
  } 


class Ticket extends Eloquent {
  public function equipment()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Equipment');
  }
```

and to get count of total tickets for the vendor (not currently open):

```
Vendor::find($id)   // retrieve particular vendor
  ->tickets()->count(); // get count on tickets table

// and this way you retrieve collection of related tickets
Vendor::find($id)   // retrieve particular vendor
  ->tickets; // get Eloquent Collection
```

Also you may find it helpful: http://softonsofa.com/querying-relations-with-eloquent-in-laravel-4/

Comment: Thank you for clearing. I got the error `Trying to get property of non-object`... should I make any Inverse Relation in the other classes (Equipment and Ticket)?

Comment: Check edited answer, now you have all the relations to make it work.

Comment: Perfect! Worked flawlessly.

Comment: A comment: You wrote the methods as `public class` instead of `public function`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to declare these relationships within their models. e.g. your `Ticket.php` model could look like this:

```
class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    public function equipment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Equipment');
    }

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Vendor');
    }

    ...
}
```

for retrieval you'd do it like this:

```
foreach (Ticket::all() as $ticket) {
    $ticket->vendor()->id;
}
```

check this section of the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

edit: for the specific query *how many tickets are open to a certain vendor*:

```
Ticket::where('open', '=', 1)->vendor()->where('id', '=', 42);
```